# Pattern matching in java: extracting digits from a string literal

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract 2 numbers from a string.
My sample code is:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static int returnInt(String pattern, String inputString) {
        Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = intPattern.matcher(inputString);
        matcher.find();
        String input = matcher.group(0);
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println(returnInt(
                        "\\d+",
                        "The following DTE jobs have been submitted to ServerFarm for execution. (farm showjobs -d -j 12774076) can be used to monitor job status. The output format is JobID : TopoName : TopoAlias : JobStatus. ( The initial job status is listed in brackets. If job status is FAILED, then the job can not be run at all! Otherwise please check job status periodically. ) :21554030 : IDM_INSTALLER_1H1N_REL11 : IDM_INSTALLER_1H1N_REL11 : WAITING (Being queueed on server farm)"));
    }
}
```

I want the output to come as: 12774076 and 21554030  but the output is only 12774076 
Kindly help!!

Comment: Put the matches.find() and the logic to extract data in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop over `matcher.find()` and return `List<Integer>` because there can be more then 1 match
for e.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static List<Integer> returnInt(String pattern, String inputString) {
        Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = intPattern.matcher(inputString);
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            output.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)));
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println(returnInt(
                        "\\d{5,}",
                        "The following DTE jobs have been submitted to ServerFarm for execution. (farm showjobs -d -j 12774076) can be used to monitor job status. The output format is JobID : TopoName : TopoAlias : JobStatus. ( The initial job status is listed in brackets. If job status is FAILED, then the job can not be run at all! Otherwise please check job status periodically. ) :21554030 : IDM_INSTALLER_1H1N_REL11 : IDM_INSTALLER_1H1N_REL11 : WAITING (Being queueed on server farm)"));
    }
}
```

output

```
[12774076, 21554030]
```

Comment: This will also get you the 1s in the String, maybe use a pattern more specific (`\\d{5,}`) to remove them

Comment: Thanks i updated my answer and corrected the original regex posted by OP